# Can't get the username in a label, console doesn't print out the values - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in my project. I want to get the Username that I have saved in Firebase to a nameLabel that I have created. The problem is that I can't get the values from Firebase. When I try to print it out it won't appear in the console. Can someone tell me why? The function is at the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var user = [User]()
    var positions = [Position]()
    var wiindow: UIWindow?
    var mapView: MKMapView?
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let distanceSpan: Double = 500
    var locationData: CLLocation!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()   

    func fetchUser() {

        let positionss = Position()

        if let fromId = positionss.fromId {
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(fromId)
            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                print(snapshot) //Dosen´t print out snapshot

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                   self.nameLabel.text = dictionary["name"] as? String  
                }
            }, withCancel: nil)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `fetchUser()` function?

Comment: positionss in initialized as a new Position() object. Is the Positions().fromId variable initialized to some value within the class upon initialization?